# what does dash e(-e) mean in sed commands?

Tags: sed

I am new to sed, and always execute one command on an input file, recently I try to use `"-e"` to work on multiple commands, but I cannot figure out how it really work, the default print is quite annoying, so I cannot figure out in which order the commands are executed.

```
   sed -e 'command 1' -e 'command 2'  input.txt
```

content of input.txt:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

**Question 1**: What is the processing flow? is it

```
command1 processes line1 and then command2 processes new-line1(processed by cmd1)
command1 processes line2 and then command2 processes new-line2(processed by cmd1)
command1 processes line3 and then command2 processes new-line3(processed by cmd1)
```

or

```
command1 processes line1
command1 processes line2
command1 processes line3
command2 processes new-line1(already processed by cmd1)
command2 processes new-line2(already processed by cmd1)
command2 processes new-line3(already processed by cmd1)
```

**Question 2:** 
As i mentioned, the default print is quite annoying, should I use -n in front of the first -e or in front of both -e?

Thanks in advance.

Edit(It seems the working flow is the first assumption):

```
input.txt

1
2
3

sed -e '{s/1/ONE/;s/2/TWO/;/3/q}' -e '{s/ONE/THREE/}' numbers.txt 

THREE
TWO
3
```

I tried the above command, and it seems the working flow is command1 processes line1, and then command2 processes new-line1(cmd1 processed it), and then cmd1 processes next line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sed -e commands are combined to create a single sed script. The following yields the same results (notice that -e is implied):

```
sed '
    s/1/ONE/
    s/2/TWO/
    /3/q
    s/ONE/THREE/
' input.txt
```

Or as a one liner:

```
sed 's/1/ONE/; s/2/TWO/; /3/q; s/ONE/THREE/' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Sed --help will tell you what -e means:

```
 -e script, --expression=script
             add the script to the commands to be executed
```

I have used sed for years, and 99% of the time I use -e, except when I want to change the file then I used -i

Question 1: I am not sure about the flow, but to play safe I always pipe it to another sed

ex:

```
cat input.txt | sed -e 'command 1' | sed -e 'command 2'
```

Question 2:  WRT default print, yes you can combine.

Default:

```
tiago@dell:~$ cat /etc/passwd | sed -e '/root/ !d'
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Quiet:

```
tiago@dell:~$ cat /etc/passwd | sed -ne '/root/p'
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried two real commands on a simple input file, it is the first flow assumption that I thought,  thanks a lot!